# IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

Running maven build on my Spring Boot app fails with IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName. Here's how the setup looks like:

```
@Bean
private DataSource getDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
          .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
          .url(environment.getProperty(VAR_URL)) // Error thrown here
          .username(environment.getProperty(VAR_NAME))
          .password(environment.getProperty(VAR_PASSWORD))
          .build();
```

The reason for the error is that the environment does not have value for the key VAR_URL during build time as it is pulled from a secret source during app startup. If I hardcode the URL, user & password details, it works. So is there a workaround I can follow to resolve this problem?

Point to note: The branch I am working on and has this issue has a quartz scheduler configured. And the same code(another branch) without quartz scheduler builds and runs fine. This makes me curious about whether if the quartz configuration with spring Datasource is causing the problem. This is my first time with quartz.

Here is the YAML with the configuration to examine:

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app
  profiles:
    active: dev
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    open-in-view: true
  datasource:
    url:
    username:
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  quartz:
    properties:
      org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
      org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
      org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
      org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: my-scheduler
      org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 3
      org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
      org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties: true
      org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000
      org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: qrtz_
      org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.class: org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
      org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.cleanShutdown: TRUE
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
    job-store-type: jdbc
```

Am I missing anything? Please suggest if there's a better way of doing this. Thank you.

### UPDATE

```
 @Bean
  public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {

    SchedulerJobFactory jobFactory = new SchedulerJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(quartzProperties.getProperties());

    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(properties);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setTriggers(reportTriggerConfig().getObject());
    return factory;
  }
```

DataSourceConfig:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
/**
 * DataSourceConfig.
 * 
 */

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataSourceConfig {

  public final Environment environment;

  @Value("${dburl:#{null}}") Optional<String> databaseUrl;
  @Value("${dbusername:#{null}}") Optional<String> username;
  @Value("${dbpassword:#{null}}") Optional<String> password;

  /**
   * Gets the dev datasource.
   *
   * @return the dev datasource
   */
  @Bean
  @Profile("dev")
  @Primary
    public DataSource getDevDatasource() {
     return DataSourceBuilder.create()
          .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
          .username(username.orElse(null))
          .url(databaseUrl.orElse(null))
          .password(password.orElse(null))
          .build();
  }
}
```

SchedulerConfig class:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;

/**
 * SchedulerConfig.
 */
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Autowired
  private QuartzProperties quartzProperties;

  /**
   * SchedulerFactoryBean.
   * @return SchedulerFactoryBean
   */
  @Bean
  public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {

    SchedulerJobFactory jobFactory = new SchedulerJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(quartzProperties.getProperties());

    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(properties);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setTriggers(reportTriggerConfig().getObject());
    return factory;
  }

  /**
   * JobDetailFactoryBean.
   * @return JobDetailFactoryBean
   */
  @Bean
  public JobDetailFactoryBean reportJobConfig() {
    JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    jobDetailFactory.setJobClass(ReportJob.class);
    jobDetailFactory.setDurability(true);
    jobDetailFactory.setGroup("pit-scheduler-group");
    return jobDetailFactory;
  }

  /**
   * CronTriggerFactoryBean.
   * @return CronTriggerFactoryBean
   */
  @Bean
  public CronTriggerFactoryBean reportTriggerConfig() {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(reportJobConfig().getObject());
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression("0 0/1 0 ? * * *");
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setGroup("pit-scheduler-group");
    return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
  }
}
```

Main SpringBootTest class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = appConfig.class)
class PitApplicationTest {

  @Autowired
  private HistoryController historyController;

  @MockBean
  private HistoryRepository historyRepository;

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {
    assertNotNull(historyController);
  }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.078 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.pit.PitApplicationTest
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.011 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/pit/job/SchedulerConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
```

Comment: and what is content of application-dev.yml?

Comment: application-dev.yml has just the actuator module -
management:
  endpoints:
    web.exposure.include: "*"

Comment: but you start application with something like -Ddburl=YOUR_URL?

Comment: Exactly, along with username & password. The app will inject dburl, dbpassword & dbusername into `Environment` during startup. That's done in a different class. The properties will not have values when the application runs in local env

Comment: you can try temporally for test purpose place your dburl, username and password in application-dev.yml

Comment: Put the just keys in application-dev and tried building. But its the same error

Comment: Your error ist not a compile (build) error. Its runtime error either you start some test with spring-context running or you start application

Comment: You are correct -  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` can be seen in the line above which is thrown due to the `@Test
  void contextLoads() {
    assertNotNull(histController);
  }` in the Main @SpringBootTest class

Comment: Have updated the main test class in the question. How can this be resolved?

Comment: You can start your test with dev Profile: @ActiveProfiles("dev") or you can define @TestConfiguration or you can remove this test

Comment: Thank you so much @WladimirDiskowski. Really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically overriding spring-boot's autoconfiguration in order to configure the datasource of this scheduler. That's why it works on the branch without the quartz scheduler (I guess you do not have the `@Bean private DataSource getDataSource()` in that branch).

You have to use `@Value` in order to retrieve the database properties from `application.yml`

e.g.

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String databaseUrl;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String password;

//and then use these strings in your getDataSource()

@Bean
private DataSource getDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
          .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
          .url(environment.getProperty(databaseUrl)) // Error thrown here
          .username(environment.getProperty(username))
          .password(environment.getProperty(password))
          .build();
```

Comment: Please note I do have `@Bean private DataSource getDataSource()` in the other branch. Since I am creating a bean, I had not put the spring.datasource.* details in applicaiton.yml. The idea is not to expose credentials as text and pull them from a different source.

Comment: Also to add, the values for `spring.datasource.*` are empty in app.yml. The values are passed as arguments on startup when run in local environment.  `environment.getProperty(VAR_NAME)` will have values in all other env(s).

Comment: Please let me know if you'd like to look at any other configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String databaseUrl;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${spring.datasource.driver_class_name}")
private String driverClassName;


@Bean
private DataSource getDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
          .driverClassName(driverClassName)
          .url(databaseUrl)
          .username(username)
          .password(password)
          .build();
```

Comment: Thank you Wladimir for the response. Could you please take a look at my response to @pleft

Comment: In addition to looking values from property files, the @Value annotation also looks for matching values from the environment.

Comment: Ok, so looks like it is mandatory to have the values either app.yaml OR make it available in the `Environment` during the build time. Am I correct? But I wonder how it works in the branch that does not have quartz configuration.

Comment: It's mandatory at runtime. If you want optional property you can set default like @Value("${key:default}"), or you can use Optional with @Value("${key:#{null}}") Optional<String> myProperty

Comment: I used `@Value("${dbusername:#{null}}") Optional<String> username;` but returned the error `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present` I suppose it's because the key for dbusername is not available in the `Environment` during build time. Had kept the spring.datasource.* properties in .yml file empty

Comment: If your Optional is empty, you can't use  username.get(). you have to use something like username.orElse(null)

Comment: Tried that but throws the error - `Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/pit/job/SchedulerConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.` Updated the questions with SchedulerFactoryBean method

Comment: can you post please your code

Comment: Added the dataSourceConfig and SchedulerConfig classes